# For what typescript allows the intersection of a primitive type and an object type containing a key of type unique symbol

Tags: typescript

```
type Key = string | number | symbol;

declare const id: unique symbol

export type Type<A extends any, Id extends Key> = {
    [id]: Id
} & A

type EUR = Type<number, 'eur'>
type USD = Type<number, 'usd'>

let eurWallet = 10 as EUR
let usdWallet = 15 as USD

eurWallet = usdWallet // TS error
```

What functionality of javascript corresponds to the possibility of intersection of a primitive type and an object type containing a key of the type unique symbol?

Comment: For exactly what you're showing, so that even though they're both numbers the compiler can tell you they're _semantically_ incompatible.

Comment: "What functionality of javascript corresponds to the possibility of intersection of a primitive type and an object type containing a key of the type unique symbol?" No functionality of *JavaScript* at all; it's a compile-time-only trick to [simulate nominal types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal), to make the "semantically incompatible" as @jonrsharpe says.  This can be written up as an answer if you want.